# Using Net::SSH Ruby library to remote command execution that requires sudo su - another user

Tags: shell, ssh, remote-access, net-ssh, rundeck

My environment is configured with SSH password-less authentication for the user 
"master" between a node Server (Rundeck server) and node Target (remote Solaris host).

On Target, I want to execute a script `/app/acme/stopApp.sh` with the user `appmanager`.

Normally, when I need to run the script manually, I use:

```
ssh master@server sudo su - appmanager
```

or simply:

```
ssh -t master@server 'sudo su - appmanager'
```

which works without the password and finally run (as appmanager):

```
/app/acme/stopApp.sh
```

But I'm unable to figure out how to reproduce these steps using Net::SSH.
When I execute `sudo su - appmanager` and then `/app/acme/stopApp.sh`, 
I'm doing it in a sub-shell, right?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/scp'
require 'crypt/blowfish'
require 'yaml'

#
# ...
#

Net::SSH.start( host, user, :password => password ) do |session|

  # It's possible to proceed in this way?
  cmd = 'sudo su - appmanager;/app/acme/stopApp.sh'  
  ses = session.exec!( cmd )

end
```

I realized that if I try to execute something like I'm on the Target server:

```
sudo su -c /app/acme/stopApp.sh appmanager
```

I receive the message below:

```
We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System Administrator. 

It usually boils down to these three things: 

 #1) Respect the privacy of others. 
 #2) Think before you type. 
 #3) With great power comes great responsibility. Password:

Password:
```

Comment: thanks the Tin Man for the improvements in text. I'm not a native English speaker so your act help me to learn more about the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a sysadmin-y answer, but I think you are authenticating twice: once to log in as "master" (using master's keypair) and then a second time "master" sudo-ing the su to "appmanager"  but using a password (hence the "lecture" message). But I think you're not answering the password challenge the second time. There are a few ways to get around this that come to mind:

1) Login as appmanager directly using that account's keypair. If you're worried about the security of the appmanager account, you can [restrict ssh remote commands](http://www.wallix.org/2011/10/18/restricting-remote-commands-over-ssh/) among other things.

2) As master, call a binary ([not a script!](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part4/section-7.html)) that is [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) as "appmanager" that simply calls the stopApp.sh script. An [example](http://qmail.jms1.net/djbdns/trigger-make.c).

3) Set the appropriate group that master is in to [NOPASSWD](http://www.ducea.com/2006/06/18/linux-tips-password-usage-in-sudo-passwd-nopasswd/) in /etc/sudoers.